# Ajuda javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Exercicio 3</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>Números dos Meses</h1>
 <input type="number" name="numeros" max="12" min="1" id="mes">
 <p id=></p>
 <input type="submit" onchange="mes()">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function mes(){
  let mes = document.getElementById('mes').value;
  switch (mes) {
   case 1:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Janeiro";
   break;
   case 2:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Fevereiro";
   break;
   case 3: 
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Março";
   break;
   case 4:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Abril";
   break;
   case 5: 
    document.getElementById('num').value;
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Maio";
   break;
   case 6:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Junho";
   break;
   case 7:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Julho";
   break;
   case 8:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Agosto";
   break;
   case 9:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Setembro";
   break;
   case 10:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Outubro";
   break;
   case 11:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Novembro";
   break;
   case 12:
   document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Dezembro";
   break;
  }
 }
 </script>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Preciso fazer esse exercicío : ** Entrar com o numero do mês e imprimir o nome do mês.(switch)** MAiS o meu código não está funcionando o erro aparece na linha 17 fala que é um erro de sintaxe e que não esperava um identifier presumo que tenha mais coisa errada alguém pode a gentileza de mostrar o caminho ? (OUTRO ERRO) o onclick do meu botão não funciona o que eu faço? (RESOLVIDO)

Comment: Depois dos `case X` não deveria ter os dois pontos?

Comment: switch (num =! 0) alterou para switch(num) ?

Comment: sim já alterei vou repostar pra ver

Answer (score 1):

Você não colocou o `input` e nem o botão em um formulário.
Tente fazer assim:

```js
let form_mes = document.getElementById("form_mes");
form_mes.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  let mes = document.getElementById("num").value;
  let mes_name = document.getElementById("mes");
  switch (mes) {
    case "1":
      mes_name.innerHTML = "Janeiro";
      break;
    case "2":
      mes_name.innerHTML = "Fevereiro";
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form_mes" onsubmit="return false;">
  <h1>Número dos Meses</h1>
  <input type="number" name="num" id="num" min="1" max="12">
  <p id="mes"></p>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltam os dois pontos  ( : ) depois de cada case

```js
switch (num) {
  case 1:
    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = "Janeiro";
    break;
}
```

Comment: o erro sumiu mas ainda não aparece nada no onclick do botão